# Unable to delete APN in Android

Tags: sony-xperia, android-5.1.1-lollipop, apn

I cannot use mobile data roaming on my Android phone. I am supposed to change to a different APN but I cannot switch APNs or delete the current "euinternet" APN. Whenever I come back to my APN settings, the "euinternet" is selected again and I can't connect to the internet.
Any ideas?

I have a Sony Xperia Z3 with Android 5.1.1.

Cheers,
Andrina

Answer (score 0):

if you can't delete the "euinternet" APN entry there is a workaround by changing it. Change the APN setting to your desired APN (e.g. web.vodafone.de) but leave the name of it to "euinternet".

This should work.

Cheers.

Comment: Works! I just have to remember to change it back after my vacation ;)

Comment: did you use settings of your domestic provider, or one in the country you were visiting?